# How to transform a Future method in a Stream method to feed a list

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this method to feed my list, but with it i'm not able to change items dynamically ( add items, drop it...) :

```dart
loadLab(String submenu, [int limit]) async {
    var parts = submenu.split('/');
    var pathSlashless = parts[0].trim();
    var subPathSlashless = parts.sublist(1).join('/').trim();

    var snapshot = await _storage.ref().child("/${submenu}");
    var retorno = await snapshot.listAll();
    List<ItemLab> conteudo = [];

    if(subPathSlashless.isEmpty || subPathSlashless == null){
      retorno.prefixes.forEach((element) {
        conteudo.add(
          ItemLab(
            tipo: 'PASTA',
            elemento: element,
          ),
        );
      });
    }
      if(limit != null){
        if(conteudo.length > limit){
          hasMore = true;
          return Stream.value(conteudo);
        }else{
          hasMore = false;
          print("menor quen ove");
        }
      }
    }

    try {
      if(subPathSlashless.isNotEmpty){
        print(subPathSlashless);
        List items;
        await databaseReference
            .collection("lab_${pathSlashless}_url")
            .snapshots().forEach((element) {
              element.docs.forEach((f) {
                if(f.data()['videos'] != null){
                    items == null ? items = f.data()['videos'] :
                    items.addAll(f.data()['videos']);
                  };
                  print("ITEMS :::: >>> ${items}");
              });
        });
    }catch(e){
      print(e);
    }

    pathSlashless = null;
    subPathSlashless = null;
    conteudo = checkDuplicateFolder(conteudo, submenu);
    print(conteudo);
    return Stream.value(conteudo);
  }
```

and the list>

```dart
return StreamBuilder(
      stream: ctrlLab.loadLab(submenu),
```

throw this error:

> type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'Stream'

What I need to do to Make the return a Stream instead of a Future

Comment: I think you have to call .snapshots() to get a stream of changes to your query, rather than .get(), which is a "tell me the current values".

Comment: Ok.. now how have to be the return?

Comment: You should probably just return a Stream, and extract what you need in something like a StreamBuilder (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html), or do some Stream-to-Stream transformation in this method first, using something like aStream.transform(...).

Comment: Please see my update